# Python web scraping involving HTML tags with attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, screen-scraping

I'm trying to make a web scraper that will parse a web-page of publications and extract the authors. The skeletal structure of the web-page is the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="contents">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="author">####I want whatever is located here ###</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to use BeautifulSoup and lxml thus far to accomplish this task, but I'm not sure how to handle the two div tags and td tag because they have attributes. In addition to this, I'm not sure whether I should rely more on BeautifulSoup or lxml or a combination of both. What should I do?

At the moment, my code looks like what is below:

```
    import re
    import urllib2,sys
    import lxml
    from lxml import etree
    from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
    from lxml.etree import tostring
    from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

    address='http://www.example.com/'
    html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    html=soup.prettify()
    html=html.replace('&nbsp', '&#160')
    html=html.replace('&iacute','&#237')
    root=fromstring(html)
```

I realize that a lot of the import statements may be redundant, but I just copied whatever I currently had in more source file.

EDIT: I suppose that I didn't make this quite clear, but I have multiple  tags in page that I want to scrape.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not clear to me from your question why you need to worry about the `div` tags -- what about doing just:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
thetd = soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'author'})
print thetd.string
```

On the HTML you give, running this emits exactly:

```
####I want whatever is located here ###
```

which appears to be what you want.  Maybe you can specify better exactly what it is you need and this super-simple snippet doesn't do -- multiple `td` tags all of class `author` of which you need to consider (all? just some? which ones?), possibly missing any such tag (what do you want to do in that case), and the like. It's hard to infer what exactly are your specs, just from this simple example and overabundant code;-).

**Edit**: if, as per the OP's latest comment, there are multiple such td tags, one per author:

```
thetds = soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class': 'author'})
for thetd in thetds:
    print thetd.string
```

...i.e., not much harder at all!-)

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I have multiple authors on the page, so I will be having multiple td tags. How do I iterate over each of them?

Answer (score 6):

or you could be using pyquery, since BeautifulSoup is not actively maintained anymore, see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html

first, install pyquery with

```
easy_install pyquery
```

then your script could be as simple as

```
from pyquery import PyQuery
d = PyQuery('http://mywebpage/')
allauthors = [ td.text() for td in d('td.author') ]
```

pyquery uses the css selector syntax familiar from jQuery which I find more intuitive than BeautifulSoup's. It uses lxml underneath, and is much faster than BeautifulSoup. But BeautifulSoup is pure python, and thus works on Google's app engine as well

Answer (score 5):

The lxml library is now the standard for parsing html in python.  The interface can seem awkward at first, but it is very serviceable for what it does.

You should let the libary handle the xml specialism, such as those escaped &entities;

```
import lxml.html

html = """<html><body><div id="container"><div id="contents"><table><tbody><tr>
          <td class="author">####I want whatever is located here, eh? &iacute; ###</td>
          </tr></tbody></table></div></div></body></html>"""

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
tds = root.cssselect("div#contents td.author")

print tds           # gives [<Element td at 84ee2cc>]
print tds[0].text   # what you want, including the 'í'
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is certainly the canonical HTML parser/processor.  But if you have just this kind of snippet you need to match, instead of building a whole hierarchical object representing the HTML, pyparsing makes it easy to define leading and trailing HTML tags as part of creating a larger search expression:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, withAttribute, SkipTo

author_td, end_td = makeHTMLTags("td")

# only interested in <td>'s where class="author"
author_td.setParseAction(withAttribute(("class","author")))

search = author_td + SkipTo(end_td)("body") + end_td

for match in search.searchString(html):
    print match.body
```

Pyparsing's makeHTMLTags function does a lot more than just emit `"<tag>"` and `"</tag>"` expressions.  It also handles:

- caseless matching of tags
- `"<tag/>"` syntax
- zero or more attribute in the opening tag
- attributes defined in arbitrary order
- attribute names with namespaces
- attribute values in single, double, or no quotes
- intervening whitespace between tag and symbols, or attribute name, '=', and value
- attributes are accessible after parsing as named results

These are the common pitfalls when considering using a regex for HTML scraping.