# Python: Can't get urllib2 to correctly read a webpage

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, urllib2, urllib, bloomberg

I am trying to get the full webpage of

'http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/economic-calendar/'

but for some reason I cannot find the function which will return the links as strings.
I would like to transform all announcements on that Bloomberg page into a CSV file but I am not sure how. The CSV file would contain things like:

Mon 12.2
Gallup US Consumer Spending Measure
[Report][Bullet8:30 AM ET

Ben Bernanke Speaks
8:30 AM ET

PMI Manufacturing Index
[Report][djStar]8:58 AM ET

ISM Mfg Index
[Report][Star]10:00 AM ET

Construction Spending
[Report][djStar]10:00 AM ET

Construction Spending
[Report][djStar]10:00 AM ET

4-Week Bill Announcement
[Report][Bullet11:00 AM ET

(which was just a copy and paste from the website).

What is the best way or best library to use?

Comment: `import csv
import urllib.urlopen
import beautifulsoup`

Comment: Could you give me a pointer on what I should be searching for? I am new to web-scraping. Thank you for you reply.

Comment: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/ http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884567/python-web-scraping-beautiful-soup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391657/python-web-scraping-involving-html-tags-with-attributes should help.

Comment: That's because there is no "function" that will return the links as strings. Python is great, but it's not magic!

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a tutorial on web scraping, you should basically look for (in the given order)

1. Url retrieving (i. e. reading from a web-page given it's url) [refer `urllib` library]
2. Html Parsing (making sense of the html & quickly accessing required content) [refer `Beautifulsoup` v4]
3. Processing the data acquired & in your case, dumping to a `csv` file. [refer `csv` library]